# Missing random Log4J2 entries in log file

Tags: log4j, log4j2, slf4j, sap-commerce-cloud

I've noticed strange behavior in how Log4j logs messages and exceptions. SOme highlights of my application: SAP Hybris 6.0.0 (aka SAP Commerce), openJDK 8, Apache Tomcat, Log4j2 2.4.1 (slf4j as facade), CentOS 7.

I utilize Log4j logger in a common way:

```
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
try
{
   //some code throwing exception
} catch (Exception e) {
   LOGGER.error("Some exception occured.");
}
```

The log4j2 xml config is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ [y] hybris Platform
  ~ 
  ~ Copyright (c) 2000-2016 SAP SE
  ~ All rights reserved.
  ~ 
  ~ This software is the confidential and proprietary information of SAP 
  ~ Hybris ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such 
  ~ Confidential Information and shall use it only in accordance with the 
  ~ terms of the license agreement you entered into with SAP Hybris.
  -->

<!-- Platform-only xml configuration for Log4j2. Not used by default, can be treated as an example -->
<!-- To enable set in local.properties: log4j2.config.xml=hybris-log4j2.xml -->
<!-- Keep in mind that xml configurations cannot be merged together unlike ones set via hybris properties. -->
<!-- shutdownHook is disabled because we invoke it programatically after shutting down hybris registry -->
<Configuration status="WARN" shutdownHook="disable" packages="de.hybris.platform.util.logging">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%-5p [%t] %X{RemoteAddr}%X{Tenant}%X{CronJob}[%c{1}] %m%n}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.hmc" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.spring.ctx.TenantIgnoreXmlWebApplicationContext" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.spring.ctx.CloseAwareApplicationContext" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.apache.ddlutils.alteration.ModelComparator" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="hsqldb.db" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.spring.IgnoreTenantScopeMetadataResolver" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.spring.ctx.ScopeTenantIgnoreDocReader" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="de.hybris.platform.util.logging.LoggingFrameworksBridgeTest" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="de.hybris.cronjobtutorial.MyJobPerformable" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But what I see in logs is quite unsual (see screenshot of some log entry).

[image]
This is how error message should look like
[image]
Looks like log event is fired, but no log message is being written (only ansi colors symbols because of enabled highlighting in log4j config). It's worth to mention that only few loggers work in this way, the majority amount of loggers work as expected.
The following construction logs only stackstrace (custom message is ommited)

```
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
try
{
   //some code throwing exception
} catch (Exception exception) {
   LOGGER.error("Some exception occured.", exception);
}
```

And even more these lines of code in some classes lead to the same result:

```
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
try
{
   //some code throwing exception
} catch (Exception exception) {
   System.out.println("Some exception occured.");
}
```

As I understand, this is not about log levels either wrong log4j configuration. I tried to omit highlighting in log4j formatter, but the result is the same - log entry is empty (and coloring symbols are gone as expected). But the stacktrace is printed. I didn't noticed, that this is environment-specific propblem, because all our environments are the same (os, configuration, etc). I suspect that something wrong with log buffers or/and communication between log4j and underlying subsystems.

**UPD**

This is how HAC Logging panel looks like

[image]

**UPD 2**

The issue seems to be hidden somewhere in tomcat logging. I've tried to update log4j configuration to utilize RollingFile type instead of SYSTEM_OUT and everything went fine, all log entries are printed correctly in rolling file. I will proceed investigation of the issue in terms of tomcat logging.

Comment: The log didn't fired. Because you have info message in the image. Can you try to enable log for your class in the hac? I think your log config xml wrong or it is in a wrong location.

Comment: @mkysoft All logs are printed as INFO, because of tomcat prepends some data. I've updated my question with relevant example.

Comment: @mkysoft Hi there! I've found the possible reason for the issue, please take a look!